# Another confusion with simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After reading some of the questions concerning `Simplify`, I still didn't find a solution to my confusion.

I want *Mathematica* to simplify

```
Simplify[(-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + 
  Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)], -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1]
```

to zero, where $x,y\in [-1,1]$. However I get the same expression.

Nevertheless, *Mathematica* doesn't seem to have a problem with:

```
Simplify[(-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x)] + 
  Sqrt[((1 - x)^3) ], -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1]
```

> 0

Or with:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] - 
  Sqrt[(1 - x)] Sqrt[(-1 + y^2)], -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1]
```

> 0

Even more surprisingly if I would just substitute $1-x = a \in [0,2]$ and $1-y^2 = b \in[0,1]$ then also

```
Simplify[-a Sqrt[a (-b)] + Sqrt[a^3 (-b)], 0 < a < 2 && 0 < b < 1]
```

> 0

is OK... What is going on? Is there something I'm implicitly assuming?

Comment: Since `Simplify` is basically a discrete minimizer of `LeafCount` under various transformations, probably the `LeafCount` of intermediate results increases more with `1-x` instead of `a`.  The transformations might be rejected before they get to the simpler expressions.

Comment: OK, that seems reasonable. Anyway to get LeafCount over this local maximum?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Sorry.  You can try your own `ComplexityFunction` or `TransformationFunctions`.  -- See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is similar to the answer by @MichaelE2, but packaged differently:

```
Simplify[
    PowerExpand[
        (-1+x) Sqrt[(1-x) (-1+y^2)]+Sqrt[(1-x)^3 (-1+y^2)],
        Assumptions->True
    ],
    -1<=x<=1 && -1<=y<=1
]
```

> 0

Answer (score 6):

If you translate the variables to be positive, you can use `PowerExpand`:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Simplify[(-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + 
  Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)], -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
   Simplify[
     PowerExpand[# /. {x -> -1 + a, y -> -1 + b}] /.
      {a -> x + 1, b -> y + 1}] &}]
(*  0  *)
```

Another odd approach is to reward expansion in terms of `1 - x` to get it past whatever bottleneck is keeping `Simplify` from working; then follow with a plain `Simplify`:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Simplify@Simplify[(-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + 
   Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)], -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1, 
  ComplexityFunction ->
   (Simplify`SimplifyCount[#] - 100 Count[#, 1 - x, Infinity] &)]
(*  0  *)
```

Comment: For the first option, it didn't seem to work on more complex inputs but when I made a function `SpecSimp[x_]:= Simplify[x, -1 <= y <= 1 && -1 <= z <= 1, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Simplify[ PowerExpand[ x /. {y -> -1 + a, z -> -1 + b] /. {a -> y + 1, b -> z + 1}] &}]` where I changed the `#` sign into the input it did. I don't understand why but OK... Thank you!!

Comment: 80k Congratulations :) I hit 50k today.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I saw that.  Congratulations to you, too. :)  I saw earlier this morning (here) we were the same number of points below the X0000 mark.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 (-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)] /. 
  Sqrt[a_^3*b_] -> a*Sqrt[a*b] // Simplify

(*  0  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Altough I cannot tell you what goes wrong with `Simplify` I would suggest implementing the simplification semi-manually. For example, with

```
te = (-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)]
```

you could use

```
te /. a_.*Sqrt[b_] :>Simplify[Sign[a], -1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1]*Sqrt[Expand[a^2 b]]
```

This brings the summands in a standard form suitable for the simplifications you need. The boundaries are not quite the same, though, and would need seperate treatment.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting is that a graph

```
  Plot3D[(-1 + x) Sqrt[(1 - x) (-1 + y^2)] + Sqrt[(1 - x)^3 (-1 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

is a non-homogenous plain

[image]

Comment: Try it with `Plot3D..., WorkingPrecision -> 16]`.  I don't know what you mean by "non-homogenous", because the equation of the plane seems to be $z = 0$, which is about as homogeneous as it gets.  Maybe you meant the holes?  They're from nonzero imaginary parts arising from rounding error.  Using `WorkingPrecision` takes care of it.

Comment: Yes, WorkingPrecision is a solution. Thank you.